# On which node must the failover manager for the AG be?

Tags: availability-groups, clustering, windows-server

I have an availability group for Windows SQL Server. It is so that instances hosting replicas must be in a Windows failover cluster. However, if the node where the failover manager is on fails, what happens?

Answer (score 0):

Failover Cluster Manager is GUI tool to manage clusters and it could be installed anywhere (i.e. on admin's workstation)